# Using google drive as a third party storage php file upload for users

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to buy a 1TB  space in google drive and create a file sharing center for users so users can upload and download files using my google drive account so the file upload will be public for all users

is that possible in google drive SDK ??

the users dose not require to login or authenticate anything just upload and download files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use service accounts to store files in an application-owned account and not require users to authenticate with their credentials:

https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts